# How to configure Spring UserCache with EhCacheBasedUserCache?

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

The goal is to configure Spring to use `UserCache` interface for retrieving user details from cache.

Spring configures default

`public class DaoAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`

when we use standard security configuration. Nothing exceptional. By default the cache logic in the `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` uses `NullUserCache' implementation.

Another implementation(wrapper?) for the interface provided is: `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.cache.EhCacheBasedUserCache`

with setter `setCache(Ehcache ehcache)`

Questions:

A. How to configure this ehcache instance, do I need full blown cache manager for my scenario?

B. How to override Spring default bean(DaoAuthenticationProvider) ? Just declare my own with the same name and then set the cache on it or autowire and then set the cache on it?

Answer (score 2):

With regards to point A, yes you need a `CacheManager`in order to get hold of an `Cache` instance with Ehcache.